# Recognize and save stream video from browser iOS

Tags: c#, ios, download, streaming

My question is about create a browser that recognize a streaming video and then save it on a local directory.

I can use c#, Someone can help me and give me some advise.

At the beginning I think that I can use c# and an array of byte to get stream but I have some problems of implementation because I cannot found the steam.

This is the code:

```
        public void StreamDownload(string currentUrl,string fileath)
    {
        int dataLength;
        int bytesRead;

        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(fileath, "test");
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
            File.Delete(filePath);


        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(currentUrl);
        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
        string oFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName("test");

        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        FileStream oFile = new FileStream(oFileName, FileMode.Append);

        dataLength = (int)response.ContentLength;


        do
        {
            bytesRead = dataStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            oFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        }
        while (bytesRead != 0);

        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, buffer);
    }
```

The problem is that it save HTML page and not the stream

wait some experts XD

thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look at the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page, since looking at your past question (almost) all of them were downvoted. This question in its current form is too broad to be considered on-topic here on SO. Don't ask about 2 completely unrelated languages. Pick the one you're best at, show what you have tried so far including the code you used, explain how the code is not working correctly and ask a specific question about that piece of code in a specific language.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Now I'll try to fix my question.